# Selecting rows, where sum of individual rows are equal to the

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe. I want to extract the rows where the individual 'ItemTotal' of each 'InvoiceNo' is equal to the 'InvoiceTotal'. 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFPt9.png)

[The source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2giUz.png)

in this example. I should be able to extract the Invoice Nos 1 & 3. coz, it's individual Item totals are equal to the Invoice total.

I tried the below code. but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.where(df.groupby('InvoiceNo')['ItemTotal'].sum() == df['InvoiceTotal'])
```

Comment: Could you post the sample data as text instead of an image?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler why did you delete your previous answer? it was correct.

Comment: groupby.transform is more pythonic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `transform`

```
np.where(df.groupby('InvoiceNo')['ItemTotal'].transform('sum') == df['InvoiceNo'])
```

Comment: got it the correct code should be `np.where(df.groupby('InvoiceNo')['ItemTotal'].transform('sum') == df['InvoiceTotal'])`  Not `df['InvoiceNo'])`. i think i made a mistake in my original question. corrected now..